# Is there any difference between setting the Brush's color alpha and the opacity?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Assuming that 0x7F alpha channel is the same as 50% opacity, is there any difference between these two Brushes?

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="FirstBrush" Color="#555555" Opacity="0.5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="SecondBrush" Color="#7F555555"/>
```

Comment: considering colour codes specifically, no, there is no difference.

Comment: AFAIK, it's amatter of the unit you use.